# Can't use data confirm

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a data-confirm for the suppression of an item, for this i'm using the easy way in haml :

```
link_to t('delete'),default_events.events_destroy_path(event), :class => 'btn', :data => {:confirm => t('messages.delete')}
```

I've done it this way in another project and it works.

Now the problem is that this project seems like not having jquery, despite fulfilling all the requirements. Here is what I did in :

my gemfile : `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.3'`

my application.coffee :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

my application.html.haml :

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %title Site
    = javascript_include_tag :jquery
    = stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => 'all'

    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
    = javascript_include_tag :application
```

my assets.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.js )
```

What can possibly be the matter here? My delete is working but the popup of data confirm never shows.

Answer (score 0):

You're including jquery twice:

1. First in the head tag.
2. Second in body tag via application.js

So just remove the ***= javascript_include_tag :jquery*** from head tag.

Comment: Doesn't fix it sadly

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Don't add version with 'jquery-rails' gem, remove 'jquery.js' from assets.rb, stop your server, run bundle update & than start your server!
Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
link_to name, url, :class => 'btn', "data-confirm" => "message"
```

It works for me.

Comment: the problem is more about my jquery that doesn't trigger than the line of data-confirm, since the exact same line in another project is working